# How to force spotlight to reimport index

Tags: macos, spotlight

I have a large remote (fuse-mounted) drive that I would like to be indexed with spotlight. After executing `sudo mdutil -i on </path/to/volume>` spotlight creates the .Spotlight-V100 directory which I presume includes the index for the folder.

When this drive is unmounted and re-mounted, it seems to lose the index. Is it possible for me to force spotlight to import the already-existing index instead of re-indexing each time?

**EDIT:** The mounted volume is xfs, and I am running OS X 10.11.4

Comment: added to original question

Comment: I can't even find a read **& write** driver for xfs. Which one do you use?

Comment: I'm unsure if this answers your question, but I'm using sshfs to mount the remote volume, which (with the right arguments) allows for read/write access.

Comment: That helps a lot. I think it's related to the different user context. The user **_spotlight** does the indexing and this user probably can't access the remote volume. Which args are you using?

Comment: I'm using reconnect, local, allow_other, defer_permissions, tranform_symlinks
Just to clarify, though, the spotlight indexing does work, but the index must be cleared and the drive must be reindexed every time it is remounted. I am trying to figure out a way to prevent this behavior.